# SAPUI5 oData V4 Read Object

Tags: json, odata, sapui5

How to read the object in UI5 with oData V4? 
Basically I want to get the JSON object from the URL service:
[image]
Ths is my onInit function in the controller.

```
onInit: function() {
var this_ = this;


this.getView().addEventDelegate({
    onBeforeShow: function(evt) {


        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("appid");

        var app_id = oModel.getData().app_id;

        this_.getView().bindElement({
            path: "zearnModel>/zearn_summary(" + app_id + ")"
        });

    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon20/2.05/en-US/96/13f1f2d88747cab21896f7216afdac/content.htm?no_cache=true):

> The OData V4 model only supports data access using bindings. It does not provide any direct access to the data.

To get the raw JSON object, all you can do is use [jQuery's ajax features](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to request the data:

```
$.get({
    url: "<your_service_url>/zearn_summary(" + app_id + ")",
    success: function(data) {
        // your success logic
    },
    error: function(error) {
        // your error logic
    }
});
```